# Can you update an Azure VM (Windows Server) without an RDP connection?

Tags: azure, windows-server-2016

I am unable to remote into my Azure virtual machine. It displays the error

> "Azure vm an authentication error has occured. The function requested
>   is not supported
>
> This could be due to CredSSP encryption oracle remediation. For more
>   information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866660"

[Microsoft states](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mckittrick/unable-to-rdp-to-virtual-machine-credssp-encryption-oracle-remediation/) that the solution is make sure the server has all updates. However, I can't seem to update the server without an RDP connection.

Is there a way to install updates on the server via the azure portal or azure cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure virtual machines have a relatively new feature (as of writing) for managing updates from the Azure portal.

These links walk through the process:
http://www.rebeladmin.com/2017/10/update-management-azure-vm/
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-updates-for-your-azure-vm/

Shortly,
1. You go to 'Update Management' in vm's operations menu.
[image: http://www.rebeladmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/update4.jpg]
2. Wait ~15 minutes for it to identify updates.
3. Click 'Schedule update deployment' and set your preferences
[image]